# ERR The entity type '***' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have entity called activity contains 2 list of models will be saved as json on db
i faced exception when i get entity say that :

```
 [ERR] The entity type 'LicenseModel' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
   System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'LicenseModel' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
```

so licenseModel **is not configured as entity** **it's column** why he see as entity.
i figure that **DateTime Properties** in LicenseModel make this issue happend, when i change type to DateOnly or DateTimeOffset the issue not happend.

i used entity framework core version 6.0.7

> i can use **[Keyless]** attibute on model or configure model in dbcontext
> like this **builder.Entity().HasNoKey();**  but i need to
> know why he see model as entity.

> Entity Configuration

```
public class ActivitiesConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Activities>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Activities> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(nameof(Activities), DbSchema).HasKey(b => b.RequestId);
            builder.ConfigureByConvention();
            builder.Property(x => x.RequestId).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.Licenses).HasConversion(x => x.ToJSON(), x => x.ToModel<List<LicenseModel>>());
            
        }
    }
```

> Entity

```
public class Activities : AuditedEntityTimeWithoutId
    {
        public Guid RequestId { get; private set; }
        public List<LicenseModel> Licenses { get; private set; }
        
    }
```

> Model

```
public class LicenseModel
    {
        public string LicenseNumber { get; private set; } 
        public DateTime IssueDate { get; private set; } 
        public DateTime ExpireDate { get; private set; }
    }
```

Thanks For Support.

Comment: I had the same error, it turned out that I added same field to two entities. That's because of the second entity in which I did not configure this field, this error occurred